# sitecore session configuration? how to set expiration?

Tags: sitecore, session-timeout, sitecore6

any ideas how sitecore manages session expiration? we tried using

```xml
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="1" />
</authentication>

<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="1"/>
```

but doesn't seem to be doing anything, so we think sitecore has its own configuration, but we can't find where

EDIT: using version 6.2.0 (rev. 100701)

Comment: What version of sitecore are you using? 6.x

Comment: 6.2.0 (rev. 100701) edited the post with it